# Uploading two files simultaneously not working

Tags: apex, file-processing

I am trying to upload two doc at a time and saving both the files. But only 1st file is getting saved not the second one. Please help.

```
public void UploadPhoto(){

        try{

            con.Name= conlastname;  
            con.First_Name__c= conemail;
            con.Family_Name__c= conphone;
            con.Gender__c= conmobilephone;
            con.Email__c = mail;
            insert con;


            Attachment a = this.tAttachment.clone(false, true, false, false);
            a.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            a.ParentId = con.id;
            this.tAttachment.Body = null;
            insert a;

            Attachment a1 = this.tAttachment1.clone(false, true, false, false);
            a1.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            a1.ParentId = con.id;
            this.tAttachment1.Body = null;
            insert a1; 

            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Thank You Registered Successfully!!Email has been Sent'));

        }catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('Exception message'+e);
        }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Try doing a loop which will add the attachments to a generic list and then insert that list that will contain multiple attachments.

Comment: @Sid did you getting any exception. i think you are getting required field exception.

Comment: I havn't checked the debug log. But only one file got uploaded not the second one

Comment: @Sid check your debug log

Answer (score 1):

Inserting multiple attachment should work if you insert a list that has multiple attachment records. Below is the code snippet.

```
  public Pagereference SaveAttachments()  
    {  
        String accId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id');  
        if(accId == null || accId == '')  
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'No record is associated. Please pass record Id in parameter.'));  
        if(FileCount == null || FileCount == '')  
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select how many files you want to upload.'));  

        List<Attachment> listToInsert = new List<Attachment>() ;  

        //Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = accid, name=myfile.name, body = myfile.body);  
        for(Attachment a: allFileList)  
        {  
            if(a.name != '' && a.name != '' && a.body != null)  
                listToInsert.add(new Attachment(parentId = accId, name = a.name, body = a.body)) ;  
        }  

        //Inserting attachments  
        if(listToInsert.size() > 0)  
        {  
            insert listToInsert ;  
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, listToInsert.size() + ' file(s) are uploaded successfully'));  
            FileCount = '' ;  
        }  
        else  
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select at-least one file'));  

        return null;  
    }
```

Comment: tip -- take a look at `String.isBlank(somestring)` method to simplify the code

Comment: But for only two browse button .. how to loop Attachment object...Can u modify my code as an example..